# Защита ключа/сертификата OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

Можно ли привязать ключ/сертификат для пользователя к физическому адресу машины (компьютеру). Как сделать так, чтоб клиентский ключ/сертификат не сработал на других компьютерах при передачи их другому лицу. Привязка по айпи невозможна, так как он очень часто меняется. Подскажите, как это сделать, подтолкните в правильное направление пожалуйста.